# How to read line in text file and replace the whole line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, replace

I want to  replace a whole line in a text document, if there is a line that begins with "truck_placement"

Can I remove the whole line when it contains "truck_placement" and then write the new text?

I tried it but it only inserts the new text und doesn't replace the whole line.

Thats the current code:

```
cordget = coordinatesentry.get()
    fin = open(save_file,"r")
    filedata = fin.read()
    fin.close

    newdata = filedata.replace("truck_placement: " , "truck_placement: " + cordget)

    fin = open(save_file, "w")
    fin.write(newdata)
    fin.close
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got some code that doesn't quite do what you want. You should post a [mre].

Comment: Maybe try and iterate though your file and write the lines that are not equal to "truck_placement" to a separate file or yours because it will just overwrite it. Would you like me to show you how?

Comment: Include some code, so we can tell where to correct?

Comment: I've included the code into the question

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? Especialy the line you want to overwrite? Because your code works just fine. It just happen that you put `truck_placement: ` back in place and only append `cordget` with the following line `newdata = filedata.replace("truck_placement: " , "truck_placement: " + cordget)`

Comment: The expected output should be: "truck_placement: (&471130de, &408caeb4, &c76af997) (&3f288b1f; &bbb0ae4f, &bf40ad9d, &bbc3317d) " , but with custom coordinates that i get from the cordget user input.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a bit until I realized what your issue actually is. I should have read your question more careful. I posted an answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to append all the lines without "truck_placement" to a new file.      This can be done with the following code:

```
original = open("truck.txt","r")
new = open("new_truck.txt","a")

for line in original:
    if "truck_placement" not in line:
        new.write(line)

original.close()
new.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either read the whole file into one string and replace the line using regular expression:

```py
import re

cordget = "(value, one) (value, two)"
save_file = "sample.txt"

with open(save_file, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

# Catch the line from "truck_placement: " until the newline character ('\n')
# and replace it with the second argument, where '\1' the catched group 
# "truck_placement: " is.
data = re.sub(r'(truck_placement: ).*\n', r'\1%s\n' % cordget, data)

with open(save_file, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(data)
```

Or you could read the file as a list of all lines and overwrite the specific line:

```py
cordget = "(value, one) (value, two)"
save_file = "sample.txt"

with open(save_file, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(data):
    if "truck_placement" in line:
        data[index] = f"truck_placement: {cordget}\n"

with open(save_file, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(data)
```